# How to use RadPieChart event handlers in Nativescript

Tags: angular, telerik, nativescript

I need to hook onto the event `pointSelectedEvent` on my `RadPieChart` Element. I have looked through the API reference sheet but it doesn't seem to give any information on how to use it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

So far I have tried:

```
@ViewChild(RadPieChartComponent, {static: false})  chart: RadPieChart ;
```

But it doesn't have the `pointSelectedEvent` to subscribe to.

Comment: What you mean by it doesn't have `pointSelected` event? Do you have a Playground sample?

Comment: In the API reference sheet there is a property called `pointSelectedEvent` "This event is fired after selecting a point in series. The event exposes an instance of the ChartEventData class" https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radpiechart

Comment: Yes I see that, but I don't get what you mean by you could not subscribe to. You can add the event listener on your template or even subscribe using renderer.

Comment: Can you show me a example how you do that?  Here is what I was doing. `chart` doesn't have `pointSelectedEvent` propriety. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8zpRGL&v=698

Comment: Why don't you simply add the listener on the template - `<RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" row="0" (pointSelected)="onPointSelected($event)">` [Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8zpRGL&v=699)

Comment: That works perfectly thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointSelectedEvent` is a static variable within the module that carries the name of the event (that's `pointSelected`).

You may add listener to the event like any other events.

```
<RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" row="0" (pointSelected)="onPointSelected($event)">
```